# SqlServer Set Serial No Auto Increment and Decrement

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have field Serial_No which just count serial no of student i used

identity(1,1)

But Problem is that if i delete row/rows it not decrease the Serial_No like

Serial_No          Name        Marks

1               Ehsan        50

3                Nouman       40

9               ejaz          56

10                  ali          30

11                saleem              78

15 abdullah 90

.... ..... ....

... .. .....

I need Serial_No auto increment but also update after delete and insert row

like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,..........

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server answer here since both are tagged in post.  I would say to leave your Identity column alone.  Let it perform the way it is designed.  Instead, create a view that selects all your columns and also includes a window function (row_number) to generate your sequential list you are looking for.

```
CREATE VIEW view_YourTable AS (
select *
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by serial_no) AS sequential_id 
FROM your_table);

SELECT * 
FROM view_YourTable
```